# How to know the line number from where the exception is coming from in PHP

Tags: php, exception, error-log

I am about to finish one project and I noticed that I am getting errors in my error_log file. I have been getting this error when I load my index.php file and in one reload I am getting 21 line lines of the error code.

I have tried debugging from the header.php file. The craziest thing is don't get any error until I load header.php file but when I call header.php in index.php file I get the errors. So I tried to catch the errors by `try` and `catch` of from PDO. In the error log file, I am getting error message so I changed my code from this `Select Query: ".$e->getMessage()` to `Select Query: ".$e->getFile()` and `Select Query: ".$e->getLine()`. But, doing this I got line number where the error is getting in not the line it was thrown from.

I think I have a problem in my select query in databse.php. Following is my select query code:

```
final protected function select($args = array(), $is_die = false){
            try {

        $this->sql = "SELECT ";
        if (isset($args['fields'])) {
            if (is_array($args['fields'])) {
                $this->sql .= implode(', ', $args['fields']);
            } else {
                $this->sql .= $args['fields'];
            }
        } else {
            $this->sql .= " * ";
        }
        $this->sql .= " FROM ";
        if (!isset($this->table) || empty($this->table)) {
            throw new Exception("Table not set");
        }
        $this->sql .= $this->table;

        /*Join Query*/
        if (isset($args['join']) && !empty($args['join'])) {
            $this->sql .= " ".$args['join'];
        }
        /*Join Query*/

        if (isset($args['where']) && !empty($args['where'])) {
            if (is_array($args['where'])) {
                $temp = array();
                foreach ($args['where'] as $column_name => $data) {
                    if (!is_array($data)) {
                        $data = array(
                            'value'     => $data,
                            'operator'  => '=',
                        );
                    }
                    $str = $column_name.' '.$data['operator'].' :'.str_replace('.', '_', $column_name);
                    $temp[] = $str;
                }
                $this->sql .= " WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $temp);
            } else {
                $this->sql .= " WHERE ".$args['where'];
            }
        }

        /*Group*/
        if (isset($args['group_by']) && !empty($args['group_by'])) {
            $this->sql .= " GROUP BY ".$args['group_by'];
        }
        /*Group*/

        /*Order*/
        if (isset($args['order_by']) && !empty($args['order_by'])) {
            $this->sql .= " ORDER BY ".$args['order_by'];
        } else {
            $this->sql .= " ORDER BY ".$this->table.".id DESC";
        }
        /*Order*/

        /*Limit*/
        if (isset($args['limit']) && !empty($args['limit'])) {
            if (is_array($args['limit'])) {
                $this->sql .= " LIMIT ".$args['limit'][0].",".$args['limit'][1];
            } else {
                $this->sql .= " LIMIT ".$args['limit'];
            }
        }
        /*Limit*/
        $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($this->sql);
        if (is_array($args['where']) || is_object($args['where'])){

            foreach ($args['where'] as $column_name => $data) {
            $value = is_array($data) ? $data['value'] : $data; //check if passed where statement was an array, fetch value if so
            if (is_int($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            }elseif (is_bool($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            }elseif (is_null($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            }else {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
            if ($param) {
                $this->stmt->bindValue(":".str_replace('.', '_', $column_name), $value, $param);
            }
        }

        }

        if ($is_die) {
            echo $this->sql;
            debugger($this->stmt);
            debugger($args, true);
        }

        $this->stmt->execute();
        $data = $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $data;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {

                error_log(
                    date('Y-m-d h:i:s A').", Select Query: ".$e->getMessage()."\r\n"
                    , 3, ERROR_PATH.'/error.log');
                return false;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                error_log(
                    date('Y-m-d h:i:s A').", General: ".$e->getMessage()."\r\n"
                    , 3, ERROR_PATH.'/error.log');
                return false;
            }
    }
```

Is there a possible way to get the line number of a file where the error is thrown form using try catch or any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pasted code to get the line number and function name in my select query.

Following is the code:

`Exception("MySQL error $mysqli->error <br> Query:<br> $sql", $msqli->errno);`

The select query will look like this after you add the above line of code:

```
final protected function select($args = array(), $is_die = false){
        try {

    $this->sql = "SELECT ";
    if (isset($args['fields'])) {
        if (is_array($args['fields'])) {
            $this->sql .= implode(', ', $args['fields']);
        } else {
            $this->sql .= $args['fields'];
        }
    } else {
        $this->sql .= " * ";
    }
    $this->sql .= " FROM ";
    if (!isset($this->table) || empty($this->table)) {
        throw new Exception("Table not set");
    }
    $this->sql .= $this->table;

    /*Join Query*/
    if (isset($args['join']) && !empty($args['join'])) {
        $this->sql .= " ".$args['join'];
    }
    /*Join Query*/

    if (isset($args['where']) && !empty($args['where'])) {
        if (is_array($args['where'])) {
            $temp = array();
            foreach ($args['where'] as $column_name => $data) {
                if (!is_array($data)) {
                    $data = array(
                        'value'     => $data,
                        'operator'  => '=',
                    );
                }
                $str = $column_name.' '.$data['operator'].' :'.str_replace('.', '_', $column_name);
                $temp[] = $str;
            }
            $this->sql .= " WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $temp);
        } else {
            $this->sql .= " WHERE ".$args['where'];
        }
    }

    /*Group*/
    if (isset($args['group_by']) && !empty($args['group_by'])) {
        $this->sql .= " GROUP BY ".$args['group_by'];
    }
    /*Group*/

    /*Order*/
    if (isset($args['order_by']) && !empty($args['order_by'])) {
        $this->sql .= " ORDER BY ".$args['order_by'];
    } else {
        $this->sql .= " ORDER BY ".$this->table.".id DESC";
    }
    /*Order*/

    /*Limit*/
    if (isset($args['limit']) && !empty($args['limit'])) {
        if (is_array($args['limit'])) {
            $this->sql .= " LIMIT ".$args['limit'][0].",".$args['limit'][1];
        } else {
            $this->sql .= " LIMIT ".$args['limit'];
        }
    }
    /*Limit*/
    $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($this->sql);
    if (is_array($args['where']) || is_object($args['where'])){

        foreach ($args['where'] as $column_name => $data) {
        $value = is_array($data) ? $data['value'] : $data; //check if passed where statement was an array, fetch value if so
        if (is_int($value)) {
            $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
        }elseif (is_bool($value)) {
            $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        }elseif (is_null($value)) {
            $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        }else {
            $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
        if ($param) {
            $this->stmt->bindValue(":".str_replace('.', '_', $column_name), $value, $param);
        }
    }

    }

    if ($is_die) {
        echo $this->sql;
        debugger($this->stmt);
        debugger($args, true);
    }

    $this->stmt->execute();
    $data = $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $data;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

            error_log(
                date('Y-m-d h:i:s A').", Select Query: ".$e->getMessage()."\r\n"
                , 3, ERROR_PATH.'/error.log');
            return false;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log(
                date('Y-m-d h:i:s A').", General: ".$e->getMessage()."\r\n"
                , 3, ERROR_PATH.'/error.log');
                Exception("MySQL error $mysqli->error <br> Query:<br> $sql", $msqli->errno);
            return false;
        }
}
```

For more information, programmers can visit this link: [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `try`, `catch` to get the exception, for the line number use`__LINE__`

For example

```
try {
  /* Your Code */
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo __LINE__.$e->getMessage() "\n";
}
```

In your code inside the catch statememt

```
"Line No : " __LINE__.date('Y-m-d h:i:s A')
```

For the line no and file path use below

```
"Line No : " __LINE__." : File Path : ".__FILE__.date('Y-m-d h:i:s A')
```

Comment: Where do I paste this code? I am not getting anything.

Comment: It gaved me the line number and I got the line number but what about the file name because I went I check to index.php, header.php and menu.php line no.152, there is no php code in that particular line.

Comment: @Alisha i have included the file name, check the updated answer

Comment: This code gave the same output as $e->getFile() and $e->getLine()

Comment: @Alisha better to use $e->getFile() and $e->getLine() , if those method exists in the object $e, you can see all the methods of $e by print_r(get_class_methods($e))